# search substring in list in python

Tags: python, list, search, substring

I need to know if the letter b (both uppercase and lowercase preferably) consist in a list.

My code:

```
List1=['apple', 'banana', 'Baboon', 'Charlie']
if 'b' in List1 or 'B' in List1:
    count_low = List1.count('b')
    count_high = List1.count('B')
    count_total = count_low + count_high   
    print "The letter b appears:", count_total, "times."
else:
    print "it did not work"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your list and go through every item, like so:

```
mycount = 0
for item in List1:
    mycount = mycount + item.lower().count('b')

if mycount == 0:
    print "It did not work"
else:
    print "The letter b appears:", mycount, "times"
```

Your code doesn't work since you're trying to count 'b' in the list instead of each string.

Or as a list comprehension:

```
mycount = sum(item.lower().count('b') for item in List1)
```

Comment: To account for both upper/lowercase, I'd change the mycount statement to use `item.lower().count('b')`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way though to search in the list without searching in each string?

Comment: `mycount = "".join(List1).lower().count('b')`

Comment: @Robo What sal said above^. My solution is just a nice and easy solution to understand :)

Comment: I just wanted to add that your solution also works for searching for characters in lists that are in other lists like tuples. That was what I really need so thanks again!

Comment: @Robo No problem! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the green tick! :)

Answer (score 0):

So the question is why doesn't this work?

Your list contains one big string, "apple, banana, Baboon, Charlie".

Add in the single quotes between elements.

Comment: I edited so that the lists now contains multiple keys. Beginners mistake :). It still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment, the code could be rewritten as:

```
count_total="".join(List1).lower().count('b')
if count_total:
   print "The letter b appears:", count_total, "times."
else:
   print "it did not work"
```

You basically join all the strings in the list and make a single long string, then lowercase it (since you don't care about case) and search for lowercase(b). The test on count_total works, because it evals to True if not zero.

Comment: Works well and easy to understand. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

The generator expression `(element.lower().count('b') for element in List1)` produces the length for each element. Pass it to `sum()` to add them up.

```
List1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'Baboon', 'Charlie']
num_times = sum(element.lower().count('b')
                for element in List1)
time_plural = "time" if num_times == 1 else "times"
print("b occurs %d %s"
      % (num_times, time_plural))
```

Output:

```
b occurs 3 times
```

If you want the count for each individual element in the list, use a list comprehension instead.  You can then `print` this list or pass it to `sum()`.

```
List1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'Baboon', 'Charlie']
num_times = [element.lower().count('b')
             for element in List1]
print("Occurrences of b:")
print(num_times)
print("Total: %s" % sum(b))
```

Output:

```
Occurrences of b:
[0, 1, 2, 0]
Total: 3
```